# Travelling with Schengen resident permit and non-EU passport

Tags: schengen, regulations, residency

I am from  Azerbaijan (non-EU country) and work in Estonia. I am holding a resident permit from Estonia (Schengen resident permit). I am wondering which countries (except the ones my [passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Azerbaijani_citizens) lets me) a resident permit from the EU and my passport let me travel outside of Europe.

I know [which](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/) you can go to with a Schengen visa and with my [passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Azerbaijani_citizens). I am wondering if it is the same list for the resident permit as well. Or for the Schengen resident permit, are there more countries which we can travel to without a visa?

Comment: Your resident permit allows you to travel to the other countries in the Schengen Area. For all other countries you **may** need a visa. I think that you will need a visa for the most if not all the countries that allow schengen visa holders to travel without an additional visa.

Comment: @Dirty-flow It seems that you missed a word or two. Your last sentence makes no sence and contradicts itself.

Comment: @Neusser what I mean is that countries like Bulgaria allows Schengen visa holders to entry and stay for a short period, but they don't allow it for Schengen resident permit holders

Comment: @Dirty-flow, in the case of Bulgaria, Azerbaijani passport holders can't go there without visa. However, schengen visa holders and resident permit holders can go there without visa

Comment: @EtibarHasanov do you have a source to confirm that you can enter Bulgaria on a Schengen resident permit?

Comment: @Dirty-flow, I entered with my resident permit

Comment: @Dirty-flow Is there a source which confirms that one cannot enter Bulgaria with Schengen residence permit?

Comment: @Neusser https://mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria states only schengen visa holders. For Romania, Croatia and Cyprus it says visa holders and residence permit holders.

Comment: @Dirty-flow No, it does not state that **only** visa-holders may enter Bulgaria. The note about residence permits of Romania, Croatia and Cyprus maybe due to the fact that they aren't in the Schengen area. This Bulgarian news states that [Schengen residence permit allows you to enter Bulgaria](https://www.novinite.com/articles/136079/Bulgaria+Opens+Doors+to+Schengen+Visa+Holders) (but it's not official, I admit).

Comment: @Dirty-flow  As an example of such an exlusion: [Irish Short Stay Visa Waiver Programme](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish%20Short%20Stay%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme) explicitly excludes holders of UK residence permit.

Answer (score 1):

There are some countries apart from the Schengen countries that would allow you visa-free entry if you hold a valid visa or residence permit issued by the Schengen state (in your case Estonia). These rules also depend on your nationality. Ex: Azerbaijani nationals can go to the Dominican Republic if they hold the visa or residence permit issued by a Schengen state.

You can find the complete list of countries here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Azerbaijani_citizens

This list keeps on changing, therefore, it is recommended that you contact the respective consulate before making your travel plans.

Comment: I am familiar with wiki page. However, it doesn't answer my question about "outside of Europe". And wiki page doesn't say anything about resident permit holder. I have the resident permit, not a visa. From where did you find out that Azerbaijani nationals can go Cuba with residence permit issued by a Schengen state.

Comment: > > It doesn't answer my question about "outside of Europe" >> UK, Georgia, Belarus etc are also in Europe but you cannot go to these countries with your RP or Visa, Do you mean Schengen?

Comment: Sorry, Cuba was added by mistake there but the Dominican Republic is not in Schengen area and unfortunately, that is that only country(outside Schengen) I can find where you can go with your RP

Comment: >>and wiki page doesn't say anything about resident permit holder>> In that case Azerbaijani nationals do indeed need a visa for the other countries except Domincan Republic (even after having the Residence Permit issued by the Schengen state) I can show you the list for some other countries where the RP is a bit more useful.

Comment: @ Arpit Bajpai, I am looking for countries oustide of Europae which I can travel with resident permit. Not interested in Europae at all. About Dominican and Mexico and other countries from the list I provided it says " a valid visa issued by a Schengen Member State" . However, I amn't holding Schengen visa, it is a resident permit provided by member state. Do they have the same power?

Comment: "Do they have the same power?" Most of the cases, yes but it is always advised to contact the embassy. In this specific case, yes you can go to Dominican with your RP. You would just need a tourist card which you get when you arrive at the airport.

Comment: @Arbit Bajpai, you mentioned "I can show you the list for some other countries where the RP is a bit more useful.". Could you please share the list?